# Install and open KeePass on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

How to install and open KeePass on Mac OS X form the User Interface and not just open a terminal and type commands?

Answer (score 3):

I use KeepassX on my macs so I don't have to use the terminal. It is free and you'll find it here:
http://www.keepassx.org

Comment: KeePassX is dead (last changelog entry from 2016). Long live [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/)!

Comment: Yes, I have recently upgraded to KeePassXC myself. It continues to offer the same functionality. Good program.

Answer (score 1):

1. downlaod [keepass portable](http://keepass.info) (zip-file)
2. install mono
3. create a shell script (e.g. `keepass.sh`) like this (assuming keepass is in `/Applications/KeePass-2/KeePass.exe`):

   ```
   mono /Applications/KeePass-2/KeePass.exe /path/to/keepass-db.kdbx
   ```
4. run `chmod 755 keepassh.sh`
5. in Finder, right-lick on the shell script and choose "Open with", then choose Terminal
6. From now on you can open Keepass from the finder by choosing the script `keepass.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Even better, I found an opensource project that's great!

You can open the KeePass database and key without problems and has pretty much the functionality of KeePass.

https://macpass.github.io/

Enjoy!

Disclaimer: I have no connection with the developer of this project.